# calculating p-value manually or using R

Tags: r, statistics

Sample size of 40 with observed mean of m1. After statistical study the mean is m2, with standard deviation sd and alpha=0.05. How do I calculate p-value either manually or in R?

Comment: This is way too broad and shows lack of any own effort. If this is a *coding* question, do some research, and edit your post to include reproducible sample data and your code attempt, explaining where you got stuck. If this is a question about general statistics, you may want to consider posting your question on Cross Validated.

Comment: I tried calculating z-score and then calculating p-value using the z-score but not sure if its the right way.

Comment: Please share sample data and code to make your reproducible. For more details, take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) I think the problem here is that this is rather a statistical question for whose [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is better suited. You might be interested in this R solution there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45156/163114